# How to deserialize XML to an object that contains an array collection in php Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, deserialization, arraycollection

I have XML in the format

```
<POS>
    <Source PseudoCCode="BOA" ISOCountry="US" AgentDutyCode="J114N">
        <RequestorID Type="11" ID="T921">
            <CompanyName Code="CP" CodeContext="123T"/>
        </RequestorID>
    </Source>
    <Source>
        <RequestorID Type="1" ID="34778"/>  
    </Source>
    <Source>
        <RequestorID Type="9" ID="ZF"/>
    </Source>
    <Source>
        <RequestorID Type="17" ID="mabaan"/>
    </Source>
</POS>
```

`

I have a php object that I want to deserialize into.

```
  class POS
  {
 /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="POS_Source", mappedBy="POS", orphanRemoval=true)
 * @Groups("Include")
 */
private $Source;

public function __construct()
{
     $this->Source = new ArrayCollection();
}
/**
 * @return ArrayCollection|OTA_POS_Source[]
 */
public function getSource(): ArrayCollection
{
    return $this->Source;
}

public function addSource(POS_Source $source): self
{
    if (!$this->Source->contains($source)) {
        $this->Source[] = $source;
        $source->setPOS($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeSource(POS_Source $source): self
{
    if ($this->Source->contains($source)) {
        $this->Source->removeElement($source);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($source->getPOS() === $this) {
            $source->setPOS(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

When I do

```
    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(
        new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader())
    );

    $metadataAwareNameConverter = new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory);

    $normalizers = [new DateTimeNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        new PropertyNormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter)];
    $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];

    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    $encoder = new XmlEncoder();

    $output[] = $encoder->decode($data,'xml');

    dump($output);


    /**
     * @var OTA_POS $pos
     */
    $pos = $serializer->deserialize($data,POS::class,'xml');

    $posSourceArray = $serializer->deserialize($pos->getSource(),'App\POS_Source[]','xml');

    dump($posSourceArray);
```

It gives me the POS object but rather than a collection of POS_Source objects it gives be an array below.

```
 POS {#839 ▼
   -id: null
   -Source: array:5 [▼
     0 => array:4 [▶]
     1 => array:1 [▶]
     2 => array:1 [▶]
     3 => array:1 [▶]
     4 => array:1 [▶]
   ]
 }
```

How can I make this work  to populate the object tree all the way to the bottom.  When I serialize from object structure to XML it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example deserializing the XML to a single `POS` instance with an `ArrayCollection` of `POS_Source` instances. I threw away all normalizers etc. not essential for deserializing this particular XML.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor;

class POS
{
    // ... just as in the question ...
}

/**
 * Minimal implementation of POS_Source for purposes of this deserialization example.
 */
class POS_Source
{
    private $RequestorID;

    public function setPOS(POS $POS)
    {
    }

    public function getRequestorID()
    {
        return $this->RequestorID;
    }

    public function setRequestorID($RequestorID)
    {
        $this->RequestorID = $RequestorID;
    }
}

$data = '<POS>
    <!-- ... the same XML as in the question ... -->
</POS>';

$normalizers = [
    new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor())
];
$encoders = [new XmlEncoder()];

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$pos = $serializer->deserialize($data,POS::class,'xml');
dump($pos);
```

Prints:

```
POS {#14
  -Source: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#11
    -elements: array:4 [
      0 => POS_Source {#17
        -RequestorID: array:3 [
          "@Type" => 11
          "@ID" => "T921"
          "CompanyName" => array:3 [
            "@Code" => "CP"
            "@CodeContext" => "123T"
            "#" => ""
          ]
        ]
      }
      1 => POS_Source {#27
        -RequestorID: array:3 [
          "@Type" => 1
          "@ID" => 34778
          "#" => ""
        ]
      }
      2 => POS_Source {#22
        -RequestorID: array:3 [
          "@Type" => 9
          "@ID" => "ZF"
          "#" => ""
        ]
      }
      3 => POS_Source {#25
        -RequestorID: array:3 [
          "@Type" => 17
          "@ID" => "mabaan"
          "#" => ""
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this working after adding   

        $pos = $serializer->deserialize($data,OTA_POS::class,'xml',['disable_type_enforcement'=> 'true']);

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer not a solution.

So it looks like deserialize doesn't support embedded php objects and that you have create a custom deserialize method.

I'm still working the solution but short answer is you have to iterate through the normalized array and then attempt to match property names. 
I'm trying to find a method to query the object for only those properties included in the serialization group doc block annotation.

Answer (score 0):

When deserializing objects containing other objects, you have to provide the `ObjectNormalizer` with a type extractor which determines type of the nested objects.

```
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor;
// ...
$normalizers = [
  new DateTimeNormalizer(),
  new ArrayDenormalizer(),
  new PropertyNormalizer(),
  new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter, null, new ReflectionExtractor()), // added type extractor as fourth argument
];
```

See also [the official documentation on this topic](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety).

Comment: Yes I did try that.

Comment: Same outcome with various iterations of the discriminator

Comment: new ObjectNormalizer(
   $classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter,       null,
new class implements PropertyTypeExtractorInterface
                { private $reflectionExtractor;
public function __construct() {  $this->reflectionExtractor = new ReflectionExtractor(); }
public function getTypes($class, $property, array $context = array())
{ if (is_a($class, OTA_POS::class, true) && 'Source' === $property) {
  return [ new Type(Type::BUILTIN_TYPE_OBJECT, true, OTA_POS_Source::class . "[]")];}
return $this->reflectionExtractor->getTypes($class, $property, $context);}},)

Comment: See my other answer. This one didn't work because when denormalizing decoded data, `Serializer` goes through the list of normalizers and asks one by one "do you know how to denormalize this data?" In this configuration `PropertyNormalizer` was the first to answer "yes", so the `ObjectNormalizer` (the only one which knew how to denormalize nested objects) didn't get it's turn at all.

Comment: This does not work and there is nothing in the documentation that says it does.  In fact in the Symfony code it says it will break

Comment: My second answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55826260/2034213) does work.